# How to get nth img tag's src attribute using parent's id

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the `src` attribute of an img tag which is the nth child of a span tag. The number of image tags are not fixed.

I just want the image's `src` which is the nth child of span id=zipcard1. Like if I pass 2 to nth-child the `src` should be "klematis1.jpg".

```
<span id="zipcard1" >
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis1.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis2.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img30" class="guess_card" src="klematis3.jpg" />
</span>
```

I tried with following code but not working:

```
var img_tag=$("#zipcard1 img : nth-child(2) ").html();
```

Comment: `$("#zipcard1 img:nth-child(2) ").attr('src');` remove space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove space from your selector as it is used to search child element. Also if you want to read `src`, then [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method should be used.

```js
alert($("#zipcard1 img:nth-child(2) ").attr('src'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="zipcard1" >
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis1.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis2.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img30" class="guess_card" src="klematis3.jpg" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq):

```js
function getSrc(index) {
  var src = $('#zipcard1 img').eq(--index).attr('src');
  alert(src);
}
getSrc(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="zipcard1">
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis1.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img31" class="guess_card" src="klematis2.jpg" />
    <img id="user_guess_img30" class="guess_card" src="klematis3.jpg" />
</span>
```

Comment: Now if i want to delete the img tag  src which got from the given code.is it like  $('#zipcard1 img').eq(--index).remove;

Comment: If you want to remove the image tag itself at an index, `$('#zipcard1 img').eq(--index).remove();` if you just want to empty its `src` atrribute, `$('#zipcard1 img').eq(--index).attr('src','')`